# Converting a 3d numpy array to data file, then insetting it after and before a certain word in another data file, finally saving the new file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large 3d numpy array of size (85, 150, 150) of floats. I would like to convert it into a data file (each number be separated by one space, the length of the line does not matter in each line) and then insert this new data file into a specific section of another datafile after and before two words: start, and end and finally savi9ng the file as 'new_file'. Is there any way to do this in Python?
My code does not seem to be working

```py
#inserting f_1 into specific section of f_2 data file

arr_reshaped_2d = arr_3d.reshape(arr_3d.shape[0], -1)
np.savetxt("f_1.txt", arr_reshaped_2d)

with open("f_1.txt", "r") as f1:
        t_1 = f_1.readlines() 

open(new_file, 'w').write(f2.seek(:start) + t1 + '\n' + f2.seek((end:))
```

Comment: Why have 'start' and 'end' delimiters? Why use a text format when a binary packed format is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

- Open one file for reading and another for writing
- Read lines from the first until `start` writing them as you go to the second
- Call `np.savetxt(HandleOfSecond, YourArray)`
- Finish reading lines from first, writing them as you go to the second